# Change column wise data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have Dataframe, in which i need to change values for one column at a time so that it does not change same values in other columns

Data Set:

```
Col-a   Col-b   Col-c
val1    abc     val1
val2    bca     bca
        bca     zzs
val2            val2
val3    xyz     zzs
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('/home/fileName.csv')
changeVal=[Col-a, Col-c]

for v in changeVal:
    n=0
    unCl=df[v].unique()
    for x in unCl:
        nV="{0}{1}".format(v,n)
        df=df.replace(v,nV)
        n=n+1
```

Expected Output: Here i am taking unique values for columns present in variable `changeVal` and then changing them with ColumnName followed by Sequence number and then replacing that value in entire dataframe. Problem is, when i do replace, it changes same values from other columns also whereas i want to modify one column at a time.

```
Col-a   Col-b   Col-c
Col-a0  abc     Col-c0
Col-a1  bca     Col-c1
        bca     Col-c2
Col-a1          Col-c3
Col-a2  xyz     Col-c2
```

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @pyd Updated expected Output

Comment: Ankit, your question is bit hard to interpret. Can you share the sample csv and what's the output you are expecting in that sample?

Comment: @ankitpandey Add some description to your outputs and what you expect in words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the df looks like:

df:

```
    Col-a   Col-b   Col-c
0   val1    abc    val1
1   val2    bca    bca
2   NaN     bca    zzs
3   val2    NaN    val2
4   val3    xyz    zzs
```

Using [`pd.factorize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.factorize.html) along with formatting will give us:

```
  df_new=pd.DataFrame({'Col-a':['Col-a{}'.format(i) for i in list(pd.factorize(df['Col-a'])[0])],'Col-b':df['Col-b'].values.tolist(),'Col-c':['Col-c{}'.format(i) for i in list(pd.factorize(df['Col-c'])[0])]})
>>df_new
    Col-a   Col-b   Col-c
0   Col-a0  abc     Col-c0
1   Col-a1  bca     Col-c1
2   Col-a-1 bca     Col-c2
3   Col-a1  NaN     Col-c3
4   Col-a2  xyz     Col-c2
```

Note that `pd.factorize` treats `NaN` as `-1` by default, hence the row 2 in Col-a has a -1. So you could drop them off before executing the above code if you want.

Hope this helps.